# Grid within Fluid fieldtype

Tags: grid, fluid-field

would someone be willing to explain to me quickly how to use Grid inside Fluid fieldtype... I can't get the syntax right... on a simple example...

{fluid_field}
{grid_field}
{grid_field:custom_field}
{/grid_field}
{/fluid_field}

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the inclusion of a `{content}` tag pair.
So your code should work when you do something like:

```
{fluid_field}
    {grid_field}
        {content}
            {content:custom_field}
        {/content}
    {/grid_field}
{/fluid_field}
```

There is a more complex illustration of this in the [EE documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/fluid.html#grid-fields).

HTH